# getting Call to a member function prepare() on null error

Tags: php, pdo

I am using a database object to run a prepared statement but getting this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/html/rsvp/lib/classes.php on line 43`

The database object I am using is (this is only part of it, but includes all relevant methods):

```
class DatabaseConnection {
  private $host = DB_HOST;
  private $user = DB_USER;
  private $pass = DB_PASS;
  private $dbname = DB_NAME;
  protected $dbConnect;
  private $stmt = NULL;
  private $result;

  public function __construct() {
    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT        => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE           => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES  => false
    );

    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try{
        $this->dbConnect = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  //Prepare statement
  public function preparedQuery($query) {
    //Unset previous stmt
    unset($this->stmt);
    //Set up new prepared statment
    $this->stmt = $this->dbConnect->prepare($query);
  }

  //Bind paramaters
  public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
  }

  //Execute statement
  public function execute() {
    return $this->stmt->execute();
  }
```

And the method I'm using to run the query is:

```
class SMS extends DatabaseConnection {

  public function __construct() {

  }

  public function createSMSSession($phoneNumber) {
    //Add to sms table
    $this->preparedQuery("INSERT INTO sms (phone_number, step) VALUES (:phonenumber, :step)");
    $this->bind(':phonenumber', $phoneNumber);
    $this->bind(':step', 1);
    $this->execute();    
  }
}
```

And, finally, the code I'm using to call the method:

```
require_once('lib/config.php');
require_once('lib/classes.php');

// Sender's phone numer
$from_number = $_REQUEST['From'];
// Receiver's phone number - Plivo number
$to_number = $_REQUEST["To"];
// The SMS text message which was received
$text = $_REQUEST["Text"];

$sms = new SMS();
$sms->createSMSSession($from_number);
```

The database credentials are defined in the config.php file. I have verified that everything is correct on that end. I have multiple methods using the same Database object with no error.

Comment: You haven't shown how your `SMS` class relates to the `DatabaseConnection` instance. If you have a disconnect function somewhere or something unsetting the handle, the excerpt won't suffice either.

Comment: The SMS class extends DatabaseConnection. It consists only of an empty __construct and the method I posted. I will edit to show the whole class.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `user`/`password` in `$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;`

Comment: @mario I change the createSMSSession function to the __construct and changed my code to new SMS($from_number). I got the same error.

Comment: @Sean the credentials are in the required config.php file.

Comment: You may find this reading useful, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the whole `SMS::__constuct` declaration if you're not actually doing anything there. Unless it invokes the `DatabaseConnection::__construct` function, you won't have a PDO handle.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. I put `DatabaseConnection::__construct();` in the __construct of the SMS class and it's working.